# using Console/cake on EC2

Tags: cakephp, amazon-ec2, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I'd to use the cakephp console on EC2 by this code :

> sudo cd /path/to/cakephp/app && Console/cake

But weirdly I got this message:

> No such file or directory

Comment: does the Console directory exist?

Comment: yes I have app/Console

Comment: Can you also check the permission of `cake`?

Comment: yes chmod -R 777 app/Console , I already did that

Answer (score 1):

Solved by installing dos2unix .
First you have to install dos2unix

```
sudo yum install dos2unix or sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

Then run:

```
sudo dos2unix /path/to/app/Console/cake
```

Maybe you need also to grant

```
chmod -R 777 app/Console
```